# APC caching not iterating variable stored in caching

Tags: php, caching

When i m using APC caching technique,Its hitting the db for the first time and next time it goes to apc caching as it should do.but when i want to iterate the same variable from apc caching,it doesnot work .Is there something more to be checked for APC caching as i m new to APC caching.

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$sql="select * from table";
     if (apc_exists($sql)) {
        $array1=apc_fetch(sql);
        echo 'from cache';
    }
    else{
$countsql3 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die("Cannot Get Pname Info: (".mysql_error().")");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($countsql3)) {$array1[] = $row;}
        print_r($array1);
        apc_store($sql,$array1,86400);
    }   
foreach(array1 as $array){}
?>
```

Its going to cache if condition but foreach loop is not getting executed ,Is anything different need to be done for variable caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the key as a string:

```
apc_store('sql', $array1, 86400);
```

And here as well:

```
if (apc_exists('sql')) {
    $array1 = apc_fetch('sql');
    echo 'from cache';
}
```

Comment: Now its not going inside if (apc_exists($sql)) condition.

Comment: sorry,its getting cached.Thanks sir.